# Hosting Identityserver4 for webapi core project in IIS

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to Identityserver4 and I got it to work with a webapi core project. I created an api project and an authserver project. I am able to generate tokens based on a username and password that resides in a database. 
However, the two projects were setup to run at startup at the same time. Once this starts to run I get two console screens running on my computer. This is kind of ugly. How can I run this silently in IIS? Do I run the two projects as separate sites?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can run it behind IIS Express on two different ports, you set this up in each one of the applications. Try this : https://andrewlock.net/configuring-urls-with-kestrel-iis-and-iis-express-with-asp-net-core/

Comment: I will read through this. Is this the same configuration I will do If I set this up in the dev enviroment?  I have IIS 7.5 on the dev web server.

Comment: Really depends, do you host against different ports or host headers etc. So far I've always deployed behind HAProxy so not an expert in this area.